# Mysqli to variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been a few days working on my project, but just stay stuck a specific part.

My problem is that i like to get a value from the database (mysqli) 
But i always receive a 0. So, no value.

This is my code:

```
    $servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";
$serialkey = $_GET['hardwareSerial'];


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$user_idSQL = "SELECT user_id FROM ss_devices WHERE serialkey = '$serialkey'";
$user_idResult = $conn->query($user_idSQL);
$user_id = $user_idResult;
```

The script should see what the userid, it is in equality with the specified serial number.

But when i take a serial number like: FJRI433. I always get a 0. But in the database has this serial number user_id: 3.

I hope someone can help me out whith this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You should really hide your database connection details...

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and need to RTFM: http://php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: I must've read this over 10 times, and I still don't get it.

Comment: query() returns a statement HANDLE, or boolean false on failure. since you say you get a zero, that means the query failed. you need `if (!$user_idResult) { die(mysqli_error($conn)); }` to tell you why. and even if it had succeeded, you need to FETCH a row of results from your result handle, before you get your actual selected id value.

Comment: I know about the vulnerable.. And this are fake database connection. What i want is this: http://prntscr.com/7wi6eq

Answer (score 2):

You are executing the query but not fetching any results.

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) has plenty of examples of using mysqli :

```
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Do stuff with the next row.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps...

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";
$serialkey = $_GET['hardwareSerial'];


$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


// Check connection
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() );
} 

$user_idSQL = "SELECT `user_id` FROM `ss_devices` WHERE `serialkey` = '$serialkey'";

if( $user_idResult = mysqli_query( $conn, $user_idSQL ) ) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_idResult)) {
        echo $row['user_id'].'<br />';
    }
}

mysqli_close( $conn );
```

Comment: Don't mix procedural and OOP style.